# Fixed Header Not showing on Page Reload

Tags: jquery

I need to state that I am not a JQuery or Java programer. This code was included within a Bootstrap template and I am not even sure where to start to fix this bug.

**The Issue**

When a user scrolls down in the window, the header becomes sticky/fixed and a background fades in. When the page reloads further down than the top, that faded background is not there and doesn't show up until the user begins to scroll on the page. So, you are unable to see the header, except for where the white lettering is on top of another element on the page.

**Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  // Header fixed and Back to top button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
      $('#header').addClass('header-fixed');
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#header').removeClass('header-fixed');
    }
  });
  $('.back-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
  });
```

**Question**

Now, my basic understanding of code, when I look at this JQuery script, tells me that this code is only run when the user scrolls per this line: `$(window).scroll(function() {`

My question is if it is possible to refactor this block code to be two stand alone functions (one for the header and one for the 'back to top' button) that are called on scroll and also on page load.

Again, I program in other languages and have very little JQuery, JavaScript and CoffeeScript knowledge. Can someone help me with this refactor to remove this bug? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to execute a binding immediately after it is bound, such as on page load, you can `trigger( 'event' )` to get it to fire.  Such as `$(window).scroll(...).trigger('scroll');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I think you'd want something like this:

```
function headerStuff(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#header').addClass('header-fixed');
  } 
  else {
    $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#header').removeClass('header-fixed');
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  headerStuff();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    headerStuff();
  });
  $('.back-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked. The only thing that I had to change was `$(document).ready(function() {`  to `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {`. Thank you @BYates! Marked as the answer.